# Привязка ссылки к ip

Tags: парсер

Доброго времени суток!
Написал парсер ссылки на файл с сайта и вывел, все работает, но у нее оказывается идет привязка к ip

http://site.ru/f09e9053fe20238a38f46a9bdfaf678c/file.txt

Собственно меняется только f09e9053fe20238a38f46a9bdfaf678c
можно ли как то это обойти?

Спасибо!

Comment: Как вариант, использовать общий прокси, т.е. парсить через прокси, а потом, если надо получить доступ к ссылке, то подкл к прокси, и скачать.
Ну или перекачивать все файлы на промежуточный сервер.

PS ссылка так же может быть привязана и ко времени (например будет не активна спустя 24 часа).

Comment: А как например сделать так, чтобы мой сервер при запросе качал файл с донора к себе во временную папку и одновременно отдавал его конечному пользователю?